# how can i get floating imgs to fill all space

Tags: html, css

I have some images width fixed sizes. I want them to fill up like a grid, like this:

[image]

But instead this happens:

[image]

How can I make them fill everything?

html:

```
<div id="product-pics">
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/566x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x566.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/566x282.png" alt="" class="tile" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.tile {
    margin: 1px;
    float: left; /* to remove the 4px gap between images */
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use some script here, like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: +1 for a clear, concise question.

Comment: is your images come dynamically ?

Comment: Even better - use Isotope, Masonry's bigger sister. She is as easy to implement, but has more tricks up her sleeve :D

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you need to change a bit the order in your HTML. Put 282x566 first and float only that one right. Leave the rest floated to the left and it should work.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3620663)

Rearranging the **HTML**:

```
<div id="product-pics">
    <img src="img/dummy/282x566.png" alt="282x566" class="tile double-h right" />

    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="282x282" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="282x282" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="282x282" class="tile" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="282x282" class="tile" />

    <img src="img/dummy/566x282.png" alt="566x282" class="tile double-w" />
    <img src="img/dummy/282x282.png" alt="282x282" class="tile" />
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
#product-pics { width: 852px; }
.tile {
    float: left;
    width: 282px;
    height: 282px;
    margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
.right { float: right; }
.double-h { height: 566px; }
.double-w { width: 566px; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use JavaScript to do this. There is an excellent plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which will produce the layout you want. Masonry uses jQuery, however there is a [Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) port that does not.

The problem you're facing is the fact that browsers lay the page out horizontally first, then vertically. Masonry changes this and creates a layout in columns.

This layout can also be produced with [CSS3 columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html), however browser support isn't great (IE10+, other modern browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Class insted of IMG tag and repeat the image, below the example for the first image,

```
.tile1 {
background:url('img/dummy/282x282.png') repeat top left;
width:100%; /* based on your area */
height:500px; /* based on the image height*/
}
```

Also check the different "repeat" option available in CSS.

Comment: I don't think the images are the same.

Comment: That's the reason I have added tile1 for the first class. Kindly read the answer first.